# z-index not working for blur effect

Tags: html, css

Let´s say I have a structure like

```
 <div class=A>
     <div class=B>
         <dialog/>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Now I want to apply blur effect on A to once I open the dialog I can use opacity to see everything behind blur and achieve the Mac opacity window effect. 
So, what I´ve done so far is this

```
 .B {
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

 .A{
    -webkit-filter: blur(7px);
    -moz-filter: blur(15px);
    -o-filter: blur(15px);
    -ms-filter: blur(15px);
    filter: blur(15px);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

As you can see I´m giving more z-index to B to be over A and I´m putting opacity to see the blur effect of A behind.

But no good results so far. Everything is blur so z-index is not working properly.

Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

I want achieve to put A on blur and leave my dialog clear but put some opacity. this is the effect that I´m looking for

https://www.google.es/search?q=css+yosemite+blur&espv=2&biw=1879&bih=962&tbm=isch&imgil=14cZk2cOQ2jrcM%253A%253BQJGhokVSp1ACMM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fstackoverflow.com%25252Fquestions%25252F25090012%25252Fos-x-yosemite-menu-background-blur-in-css&source=iu&pf=m&fir=14cZk2cOQ2jrcM%253A%252CQJGhokVSp1ACMM%252C_&usg=__kfibV3Ck2ZbNQJ6GLEoNrGET1Cg%3D&ved=0CFQQyjc&ei=j2BMVYncKcvwUq_jgOAI#imgrc=14cZk2cOQ2jrcM%253A%3BQJGhokVSp1ACMM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fi.stack.imgur.com%252F4sBMR.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fstackoverflow.com%252Fquestions%252F25090012%252Fos-x-yosemite-menu-background-blur-in-css%3B788%3B468

Regards.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or jsFiddle? The `z-index` in your code is redundant and doesn't affect the output.

Comment: have you tried to give position absolute to .B? Should work also with relative position but I have always seen/used it with absolute

Comment: z-index only work if you gave `position` to your element. You have no `position` rule in your `.A`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a7rfp5y8/

Comment: @Manoz thanks for the code, but SAMPLE of B looks blur. I want to see it clear.

Comment: @paul : just change `background:red;` of `.B` in fiddle of @Manoz. please clarify more what you want to achieve  and what is the problem you are facing by using the fiddle that is provided by @Manoz?

Comment: I put extra information on the ticket thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Manoz jsfiddle I achieved what you want.

But you need to change the structure. Just like the previous answer told you to do so. The only difference is I added position absolute to the `.A` so it sits underneath the `.B`

```css
.B {
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    background:white;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
}
.A {
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    -moz-filter: blur(1px);
    -o-filter: blur(1px);
    -ms-filter: blur(1px);
    filter: blur(1px);
    background:blue;
    z-index: 1;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class=A>
        
    </div>
    <div  class=B>
         <h2>SAMPLE</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can add opacity to the text if you desire. Adjust accordingly.

### EDIT 1:

So you want to keep the same structure.. then here it is:

```css
.B {
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
    background:white;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    position: relative;
}

.A:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    -moz-filter: blur(1px);
    -o-filter: blur(1px);
    -ms-filter: blur(1px);
    filter: blur(1px);
    background:blue;
    z-index: 1;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0 ;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
     <div class="B">
         <h2>SAMPLE</h2>
     </div>
 </div>
```

You can adjust the size of the `:before` accordingly ..

Comment: I cannot extract B from A, that´s the complex part of this story :)

Comment: I need to blur the whole body of my page, when I open the dialog. And all my pages are in there, and some of them has dialogs that are inside the page. That´s why I cannot just extract the dialog from the A

Comment: I´ll play with this to see if I can make it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
-webkit-filter: blur(7px);
-moz-filter: blur(15px);
-o-filter: blur(15px);
-ms-filter: blur(15px);
filter: blur(15px);
```

Filter is a inherited property and affect the content of `A` too.

You need the structure like this to avoid effect's from `A`:

```
<div class=A></div>
<div class=B>
    <dialog/>
</div>
```

May be better to use `box-shadow` for `blur` effect?

Comment: I need the effects of A on dialog of B as well.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that you need to is separate the two divs

```
 <div class="A">
 </div>
     <div class="B">
     </div>
```

And next, you have to give position property to the div that is going to be in front of the blurred section

```
.B {
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-wrapper {
  position: relative; /* It must be given to parent element */
  width: 300px; /* setting width as 300px */
  height: 300px; /* setting height as 300px */
}

.A {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex; /* to center the box */
  align-items: center; /* to make vertically center */
  justify-content: center; /* to make horizontally center */
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px); /* blurs at 1px */
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/300'); /* setting dummy image at background */
}

.B {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="A">
    <div class="B">
      Dummy text
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```